# CKEditor 4 dynamic select in a dialog

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Trying to figure out how to dynamically populate a select menu in a dialog... in all my attempts thus far, I haven't been able to get it work correctly.

Answer (score 8):

I think what you're trying to do is populate a drop down dynamically in your
plugin. And for whatever reason, that drop down needs to be populated while the
dialog is open.

If so, here is what I did for a similar situation:

```
{
    type: 'select',
    id: 'exam_ID',
    label: 'Select Exam',
    items : [ ['--- Select an Exam---',0] ],
    setup : function(element) {
        var element_id = '#' + this.getInputElement().$.id;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'lib/ckeditor/plugins/customExam/utilities/listExams.aspx',
            data: '{"cpID":' + window.parent.$("#cpID").val() + '}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data.DATA, function(index, item) {
                    $(element_id).get(0).options[$(element_id).get(0).options.length] = new Option(item[1], item[0]);
                });
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            } 
        });
    }

}
```

The key was finding the element ID that CKEditor sets, which is not the `id` in the element definition. You can use that `id` for other functions, but if you plan on doing any updating of the element, you need to get the CKEditor DOM element.

There might be a better way to do this, but this works for me.

Comment: I've noticed that at `setup:` you're not using the `element` argument -- is that ok?

Comment: I can't work out why, but I had to use the `onLoad` event rather than `setup` when using ckeditor 4.5.4. [dialog uiElement reference](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.uiElement).

Answer (score 4):

```
elements: [
                {
                    type: 'select',
                    id: 'test',
                    label: 'test label',
                    items: [
                        ['Please Choose', '']
                    ],
                    onLoad: function(element) {
                        this.add('Option 1', '1');
                        this.add('Option 2', '2');
                    }              
               }
        ]
```

If you want to add or remove items when dialog opens for editing. You can use `setup` call. Place it above or below `onLoad` definition.

```
                    setup: function(element) {
                        this.clear();

                        this.add('Please Choose', '');
                        this.add('Option 1', '1');
                        this.add('Option 2', '2');

                        this.setValue(element.getText());
                    },
```

Answer (score 2):

Bob,

Here's a snippet that changes the items for an existing select menu.  But, you can add your own, get the values dynamically, etc.

```
        //for button we just want to limit the button type to button
    if ( dialogName == 'button' ) {

        // updates the info tab 
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
        var typeDef = infoTab.get( 'type' );
        var buttonType = new Array("Button", "button");
        var myItems = new Array (buttonType); 
        typeDef['items'] = myItems;
```

If that doesn't help, provide additional details on actual vs. expected results.

Comment: I want to populate a select dynamically such as:

Example:

`
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'foo', function( editor )
 {
  return {
   title : 'test',
   resizable : CKEDITOR.DIALOG_RESIZE_BOTH,
   minWidth : 500,
   minHeight : 400,
   contents : [
    
      {
       type : 'select',
       label : 'Select an exam:',
       width : 200,
       items : [ 
          ['one',1],['two',2]
         ]
      }
     
     ]
     }
   ]
  };
 });
`

Comment: Your snippet was helpful... but basically what I need to do is populate the select menu via an external source, ie something like an ajax call perhaps... there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this. Is there isn't, is it possible "wrap" everything I want to do inside of an iframe that hits another webpage. That would eliminate me having to deal with the cumbersome definitions inside of the editor.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what's stopping you from making an AJAX call?   These onDefinitions are only called once, not every time the user clicks the plugin.  Or load the data during startup and stash it in DATA or somewhere else and then use it.

Answer (score 1):

Improved code that use the add() method and select the correct item in the list.

```js
{
    type: 'select',
    label: 'Select a page',
    id: 'localPage',
    items: [['', '']],
    setup: function(data) {
        var self = this;
        $.get('/pages.php', function(items) {
            items.forEach(function(item) {
                self.add(item[0], item[1]);
            });
            if (data.localPage) {
                self.setValue(data.localPage || '');
            }
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('An error occurred while getting the pages.');
        });
    },
}
```

pages.php sample script:

```php
$pages = [
    ['Contact', '{!! page:4 !!}'],
    ['About', '{!! page:5 !!}'],
    ['Home page', '{!! page:1 !!}'],
];

return json_encode($pages);
```